# What are some approaches to build a high-availability OpenStack cluster?

Tags: linux, cloud, high-availability, openstack

What are some techniques to make the openstack services operate in a high-availability manner?  The OpenStack services appear to be single points of failure.  What are some methods to make these services more robust?

Comment: [OpenStack High Availability Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-ha/content/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.slideshare.net/openstack/openstackdesignsummithapairsarenottheonlyanswer-copypdf

Slide about resiliency versus redundancy.  HA pairs are kind of antithetical to the elastic model.  But you can still ensure resiliency without HA at least in the traditional sense.